# Eclipse: Dynamic Web Project with static front end

Tags: java, jsp

can any one give reference on the java project which have properties of static front end with dynamic data. when any event occur the design part will remain same only data fetch according to occurrences of event.

Comment: What do you mean by static frontend?

Comment: where page design will remain same but based on user input data fetch through database and populate in web page

Comment: Well, its pretty much everywhere, what do you mean by dynamic front end then? I cannot see the difference. Basically you have fronend with bunch of javascript code that is requesting the data from your backend and updates the view accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry you talking Java Server Pages. I do not know exact use case for them.